# Issue Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, testing

I am getting the below error while doing react testing.

> Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

[image]

I have installed  yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
and below plugins also added in babel.config and babelrc files
[image]

[image]

But still getting the same error